# Merging [tikz] and [pgf] tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag-wiki for [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz) currently states:

> Questions tagged with [tikz] are about
>   the higher-level drawing language
>   Ti*k*Z built over the PGF
>   graphics framework. Questions
>   specifically about the PGF layer
>   should be tagged with [pgf] instead.

This is nice in theory, but in reality the tags are somewhat randomly applied to questions. Should we make [pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgf) an synonym of [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz) (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Seems sensible to me. Experts in one are likely to be experts in the other.

Comment: I was the one who wrote the above description, and it was really because I was playing around with my tag wiki editor privileges.  I'm happy with the result of the discussion here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this is one of those ones like the `latex` tag.  It's misused so much that `pgf` isn't a suitable tag.  Whilst I can imagine a question being pure `pgf` (for example, something using the maths parser or a package like `pgfpages`), these are probably drowned in the morass of `tikz` questions.

The solution for `latex` is probably applicable.  There should be a `pgf-core` tag for questions that are *really* about pgf and not about tikz, whilst `pgf` itself should be merged with `tikz`.

To address Will's point: I would look at a `tikz` question expecting to be able to make a contribution (meaning that I would reckon on being able to say something sensible more than 50% of the time), but with a `pgf-core` tag then I would look expecting to learn something from those more advanced in the Dark Arts than me.

---

Combining this with Stefan's idea, this looks like a good idea:

1. Rename `tikz` to `tikz-pgf`
2. Merge `pgf` into `tikz-pgf`
3. Make `tikz` and `pgf` synonyms of `tikz-pgf`
4. Create `pgf-core`

Comment: Good suggestions: I agree!

Comment: +1, [pgf-core] is a good idea.  For the sake of nailing the suggestion down, the idea is to make [pgf] a synonym of [tikz]?

Comment: Since this seems to be the consensus, maybe some mod can go ahead and implement it (as mere users can't rename tags).

Answer (score 7):

I would create a general tag `{tikz-pgf}` suggesting to make both `{tikz}` and `{pgf}` synomyms to it, then merge (the popular frontend as first name part).

- pgf core questions should not get the tikz (frontend) tag
- though tikz questions would fit into a pgf category the tag `[pgf]` doesn't seem natural to  frontend user

The documentation (manual) is a merge as well.

Comment: Of course with the intention of keeping the tikz taxonomist badge for the user who created `{tikz}`, I guess doing it by firstly renaming `{tikz}` to `{tikz-pgf}` keeps that.

Comment: I like this.  For one, if someone ends up with `tikz-pgf` as the tag, then they're not going to go hunting round for a `pgf`-specific tag unless they really mean it.

Answer (score 3):

The case I see for not doing it is that PGF isn't just the plumbing of Tikz, it's also the plumbing for Beamer, so some PGF questions aren't Tikz questions.

Pretty marginal objection in practice, Will is right, we should merge.

Answer (score 2):

Right, I *think* I've done it, but it was the first time that I've used the tag moderator tools so I may have messed up.  In particular, there didn't seem to be a "rename" tool so the person who got the TikZ-taxonomist badge may just have lost it (except that I don't think badges can be lost).

The one bit I haven't done is create the tag `pgf-core`.  Of course, anyone can do this: it just involves finding (or asking) a question that is pure pgf and tagging it appropriately.

Comment: It seems that Łukasz Lew created the former "tikz" tag, because he now owns a taxonomist badge for "No longer available". And you earned this badge for "tikz-pgf". ;-)

Comment: Thank you. 25% of our taxonomist badges are now "no longer available" :) (we did have that stat at 100% for quite some time (the [tag:latex] tag), so it's am improvement)

Comment: @lockstep: you spotted my cunning plan!  This whole thing was a setup to get me another badge.

Comment: Badges are not supposed to be lost.  From [the badges FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), "The site admin has stated multiple times that, by design, badges cannot be lost or revoked, unless they were obtained by cheating."

Comment: So Andrew can lose his taxonomist badge? ;)

Comment: No, no, they can't take that away from me.

Comment: @Caramdir: it's not cheating when moderators do it....

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there has been a TikZ tag wiki entry - now it's gone. Perhaps anybody does remember the text and could recreate it including an update regarding `{pgf}` and `{pgf-core}`.

Comment: Botheration and double botheration.  I _knew_ it seemed too easy.

Comment: According to google, there was nothing in the tikz tag wiki as of 14th November.  Nor for pgf on the 16th.

Comment: @Andrew: I've checked the google cache as well in order to find the original text, but it wasn't there. Fortunately, I found the text in my activity history in a wiki revision. The original text has been written by Matthew Leingang. http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/info

Comment: I wonder why it is not in Google cache (though google seems to treat the SE sites special). Btw, there is a nice new `[tag:some-tag]` syntax (see [meta.so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482)).

Comment: @Caramdir: that's nice! I'm happy to have a syntax for tags.